# package installation - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried installing the package dplyr using the R cmd command but got the below error not sure what would be the issue.

```
R CMD INSTALL dplyr_0.7.8.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -    I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -DBOOST_NO_INT64_T -        DBOOST_NO_INTEGRAL_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_LONG_LONG -    DRCPP_USING_UTF8_ERROR_STRING -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-            3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-    3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-    3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include  -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -    I"/usr/lib64/R/library/bindrcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/plogr/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2  -c         RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* _dplyr_get_date_classes()’:
RcppExports.cpp:274: error: ‘isLongjumpSentinel’ is not a member     of ‘Rcpp::internal’
RcppExports.cpp:276: error: ‘resumeJump’ is not a member of     ‘Rcpp::internal’
RcppExports.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* _dplyr_get_time_classes()’:
RcppExports.cpp:307: error: ‘isLongjumpSentinel’ is not a member of ‘Rcpp::internal’
RcppExports.cpp:309: error: ‘resumeJump’ is not a member of     ‘Rcpp::internal’
RcppExports.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* _dplyr_build_index_cpp(SEXPREC*)’:
RcppExports.cpp:341: error: ‘isLongjumpSentinel’ is not a member of ‘Rcpp::internal’
RcppExports.cpp:343: error: ‘resumeJump’ is not a member of ‘Rcpp::internal’
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/dplyr’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/dplyr’
```

please suggest. thanks.

Comment: why are you installing from cmd? why not `install.packages`?

Comment: installing it on linux server, with no internet.

Comment: Which Rcpp version is installed on the server?

Comment: reinstall Rcpp after removing it and try again installing dplyr

Comment: do i need to remove Rccp and then install dplyr? i'm confused